# Determine selected options based on many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I have three tables: products, categories and category_product.

In my edit form page I'm displaying the categories and subcategories values in a select box.
The chosen category options are saved in the pivot table category_product. This table has product_id and category_id.

Here's my code.

Product model

```
public function category() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Category');
}
```

Category model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

edit product page view:

```
<select name="category_id[]" class="form-control" multiple size = 10>
   @foreach ($parentCategories as $parentCategory)
       <option value="{{ $parentCategory->id }}">{{ $parentCategory->name }}</option>
       @if(count($parentCategory->subcategory))
         @include('includes.subcats-select',['subcategories' => $parentCategory->subcategory])
       @endif
   @endforeach
</select>
```

subcats-select view

```
@foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)
  <option value="{{ $subcategory->id }}">---{{ $subcategory->name }}</option>
    @if(count($subcategory->subcategory))
      @include('includes.subcats-select',['subcategories' => $subcategory->subcategory])
    @endif
  </div>
@endforeach
```

How can I put "selected" attribute to the chosen category options, so when I edit the page to apply the changes properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get [pivot table columns](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns) the following way:

Product model

```php
public function category() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Category')->withPivot('selected');
}
```

edit product page View:

```
<select name="category_id[]" class="form-control" multiple size = 10>
   @foreach ($parentCategories as $parentCategory)
       <option value="{{ $parentCategory->id }}" selected="{{ $parentCategory->pivot->selected }}">
           {{ $parentCategory->name }}
       </option>
       @if(count($parentCategory->subcategory))
         @include('includes.subcats-select',['subcategories' => $parentCategory->subcategory])
       @endif
   @endforeach
</select>
```

---

**EDIT**: While the above answer might be helpful for others, it doesn't answer the question. So here's my second try after some clarification in the chat.

```
<select name="category_id[]" class="form-control" multiple size = 10>
   @foreach ($parentCategories as $parentCategory)
       <option value="{{ $parentCategory->id }}"{{ $product->category->contains($parentCategory->id) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
           {{ $parentCategory->name }}
       </option>
       @if(count($parentCategory->subcategory))
         @include('includes.subcats-select',['subcategories' => $parentCategory->subcategory])
       @endif
   @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: I've updated the product model and tried with your code but I'm getting this error: Trying to get property 'selected' of non-object.

Comment: So `$parentCategory` is `$product->category`?

Comment: with dd($parentCategories) I'm getting result but with dd($product-category) I'm getting SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_product.selected' in 'field list'

Comment: if I remove ->withPivot('selected') from the model, dd($product->category) works fine

Comment: selected="{{ $parentCategory->pivot->selected }}" gives error screen Trying to get property 'selected' of non-object

Comment: Don't you have the column `selected` in your `category_product` table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232852/discussion-between-user2519032-and-shaedrich).

Comment: No, I don't have "selected" column. Why would I have?
I have category_id and product_id